# Issues creating toggle button

Tags: swift, uibutton

I am trying to create a button that reads "Special 1" then when it is clicked, the button reads "USED" and it stays as "USED" and doesn't allow the reader to toggle it back.

For example, the Twitter "follow" button can be pressed and then the button is changed to "following". However on Twitter, the user can click the "following" button and it will change back to "follow".

For my app, I want the user to be able to click "Special 1" and then the button is changed to "USED" and it remains that way forever.

Below is the attached code that I have created so far. The problem with my code so far is that the button doesn't read "Special 1" or "USED" when it is selected, the only thing it contains is the colors. The colors change how I want them to, but I can't get the words to appear and change.

```
import UIKit

class SpecialOneBTN: UIButton {

    var isOn = false

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initButton()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initButton()
    }

    func initButton() {
        layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.height/2
        setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 193.0/255.0, blue: 95.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0), for: .normal)
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(SpecialOneBTN.buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside  )
    }

    @objc func buttonPressed() {
        activateButton(bool: !isOn)

    }

    func activateButton(bool: Bool) {
        isOn = bool
        let color = bool ? UIColor(red: 102.0/255.0, green: 102.0/255.0, blue: 100.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0) : UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 193.0/255.0, blue: 95.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        let titleColor = bool ? UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.0) : UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.0)
        let title = bool ? "USED" : "Special 1"

        setTitle(title, for: .normal)
        setTitleColor(titleColor, for: .normal)
        backgroundColor = color
   }
}
```

Comment: FYI - your `UIColor` code is wrong. The values need to be in the range 0.0 - 1.0. Divide your numbers by 255.

Comment: okay I fixed that do you know how to fix what I'm asking @rmaddy